# Unable to use python3

Tags: 12.04, python, python3

Unknowingly i deleted the python folders in the `/` (root) directory, so I got this error when I tried to run python3.

I reinstalled `python3.2.3` version by manually downlading and installing with the help of `read me` file. Still facing the same problem.

```
next@NEXT-IN-WS010:~$ python3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/sysconfig.py", line 334, in _init_posix
_parse_makefile(makefile, vars)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/sysconfig.py", line 220, in _parse_makefile
with open(filename, errors="surrogateescape") as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.2/config-3.2mu/Makefile'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site.py", line 529, in <module>
main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site.py", line 517, in main
known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site.py", line 263, in addusersitepackages
user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site.py", line 238, in getusersitepackages
user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site.py", line 228, in getuserbase
USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/sysconfig.py", line 577, in get_config_var
return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/sysconfig.py", line 474, in get_config_vars
_init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/sysconfig.py", line 339, in _init_posix
raise IOError(msg)
IOError: invalid Python installation: unable to open /usr/local/lib/python3.2/config-3.2mu/Makefile (No such file or directory)
```

Is there a solution or should I reinstall the operating system

Note: if it is possible to open any higher versions like 3.3(or above) instead of 3.2.3, it is most welcome

**Edit 1:** When I tried to use `sudo apt-get install python3`, it says python3 is already in newest version.

Comment: Remove the locally installed one and do `sudo apt-get install python3`

Comment: How to remove the locally installed python3 version? @heemayl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution again.

When I was finding through various links and finally found in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871795/removing-second-python-install).

Just have to reinstall the `python3` version and enter `hash -r` to restore the version back, by the following commands.

```
cd "to the directory where downloaded python is"
./configure
make
make test
sudo make install
hash -r
```

Comment: Please, add a complete answer. Did you do `sudo apt-get purge python3` and `sudo apt-get install python3`? After than `hash -r ...` what? Please, accept your answer when you think it is complete.